# str_replace and arrays that are not in order

Tags: php

I'm stuck with this.

I've got a huge template that goes like this (simplified for this question):

```
$str = '[a] [b] [c]';
```

Then I have an array containing those above values:

```
$arr = array('[a]','[b]','[c]','[d]');
```

And finally, containing the values for replace comes an array that does not match the above one.

```
$rep = array("[d]" => "dVal","[a]" => "aVal","[b]" => "bVal", "[c]" => "cVal");
```

Can I some how, by some technique or any other php function match the `$rep` array to replace the key with the same name in `$str`. I current use `str_replace`.

```
sr_replace($arr,$rep,$str);//
```

The key names and names in `$str` are the same.

Comment: Did you try `str_replace(array_keys($rep), array_values($rep), $str)`?

Comment: No. Wait a second I'll try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str_replace(array_keys($rep), array_values($rep), $str)
```

Comment: You don't need the array_values().